# Где найти описание параметров, которые даются файлам в /etc/X11/trusted. Astra Linux(1.7)

Tags: linux, astra-linux

Хотел бы поинтересоваться, где найти: что значат параметры, которыми помечаются файлы в файле /etc/X11/trusted?

Например, файл /usr/bin/fly-wm помечен значением WM_R, а fly-vkbd KBD_R и PROP_R. Что они значат?
Вот так это выглядит:

```
/usr/bin/Xnest(NESTED_R|MAC_R|KBD_R)
```

Да и вообще где хоть про этот trusted почитать, нашёл только пару мелких упоминаний.

Answer (score 0):

Это файл конфигурации xparsec. Документацию к этому наверное надо искать в man parsec